# Make some changes in the reference at the back of thesis

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am using `memoir` class for writing thesis. For the references, I use `apacite` package.

In the `thesis.tex` file, I use `\bibliography{myrefs}` after the `\backmatter` command.

In the class file, the codes for `apacite` referencing style is shown below:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliograpy
% - Font size = 10pt = \footnotesize
% - Double spacing between entries
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\newcounter{lbibcount}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\footnotesize}
%\setlength\bibitemsep{\onelineskip}
\setlength\bibleftmargin{2em}
\setlength\bibindent{-2em}

\patchcommand{\bibitem}{\SingleSpacing}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*\bibname{\texorpdfstring{REFERENCES}{References}}}
```

And I get the output as below:

[image: below].

I want some changes to be done to the output style.

I want the references to be:

1) the year in bold face e.g (**2011**)

2) the volume also in the bold face e.g (**3**)

3) the title of book and the journal name to be in the italic, e.g  *Biochemistry of lipids, lipoproteins and membranes*

4) finally, I want the all the names to be listed and not like in the references in the yellow shaded region, where the authors more than 6 names are substitued with the word "others".

Is there any way to acheive what I want with minimum work-around.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to prepare a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? Since you don't use `biblatex`, but `apacite` and want a minimal-change solution, I will re-tag your question to reflect that.

Comment: Are there anny news here?